# How to get resumptiontoken value from given xml

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting an XML from a OAI-PMH request which contains a resumption token to get next set of records. How to get the resumption token Value and its other attributes such as completeListSize etc.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="static/style.xsl"?><OAI-PMH xmlns="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/OAI-PMH.xsd"><responseDate>2015-06-24T16:45:25Z</responseDate>
<request verb="ListRecords" metadataPrefix="uketd_dc">http://publications.iadb.org/oai/request</request>
<ListRecords>
    <record>
        <header>
            <identifier>oai:publications.iadb.org:11319/195</identifier>
            <datestamp>2015-06-12T23:02:48Z</datestamp>
            <setSpec>com_123456789_1</setSpec>
            <setSpec>col_123456789_3</setSpec>
        </header>
        <metadata></metadata>
    </record>  
 <resumptionToken completeListSize="6305" cursor="0">MToxMDB8Mjp8Mzp8NDp8NTp1a2V0ZF9kYw==</resumptionToken>
</ListRecords>
```

I tried the below code

```
 XDocument root= XDocument .Load("http://publications.iadb.org/oai/request?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=uketd_dc");
        var tokenValue= root.Element("resumptionToken").Value;
```

Its returning object reference error.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` returns an immediate child element. From the context of your document, the only element available to you is `OAI-PMH` - this is why you're getting the null reference exception.

In addition, your target element has a *namespace* as defined by the default namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`) in the root `OAI-PMH` element.

You can use `Descendants` to find *any* element in the document with your required name, so this short code should work:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/";
var tokenValue = (string)root.Descendants(ns + "resumptionToken").Single();
```